# Sistema de hashtags em PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de hashtags em `PHP`, e a minha dúvida é a seguinte:

Há como eu fazer um `SELECT` das publicações a partir do conteúdo?

Por exemplo, o conteúdo salvo no banco é:

> oi, tudo bem com vocês? #bomdia

Nno caso o `SELECT` seria algo como `SELECT * FROM msgs WHERE conteudo LIKE %#bomdia%` ?

Vi vários artigos onde, ao salvar a publicação no banco de dados, todas as hashtags detectadas são salvas em uma coluna separada na tabela, por exemplo "hashtags".

Qual a melhor maneira de se fazer isso?

Comment: O melhor é separar e salvar cada hashtag referente à publicação. Só não entendi bem sua duvida. Problema para identificar a hashtag no texto?

Comment: A duvida em sí é sobre a melhor forma de se fazer, ou as duas resultam no mesmo?

Comment: O melhor é separar um campo só para hashtags pois o usuario vai poder fazer buscas mais filtradas... eu faria assim...

Comment: Entendi, então acho que farei assim mesmo... Obrigado!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Como mencionando nos comentários, o ideal é separar a tag da mensagem. Eu iria um pouco mais além e faria uma tabela só para as tags, levando em conta que uma mensagem pode ter varias ou nenhuma tag:

[image: DER]

Repare que adicionei um índice do tipo `UNIQUE` no nome da tag, para evitar duplicadas e agilizar as pesquisas.

Para extrair as tags da mensagem utilize o [`preg_match_all()`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.preg-match-all.php), salvando no banco somente o texto da tag, sem a cerquilha (`#`):

```
<?php

class Mensagem {

    protected $mensagem;
    protected $tags = [];

    public function __construct($messagem)
    {
        $this->mensagem = $messagem;
        $this->extractTags($messagem);
    }

    private function extractTags($mensagem)
    {
        // Casa tags como #dia #feliz #chateado
        // Não casa caracteres especias #so-pt
        $pattern = '/#(\w+)/';

        // Alternativa para incluir outros caracteres
        // Basta incluir entre os colchetes
        //$pattern = '/#([\w-]+)/';

        preg_match_all($pattern, $mensagem, $tags);

        // Utiliza o vetor com os grupos capturados entre parenteses
        $this->tags = $tags[1];
    }

    public function getMensagem()
    {
        return $this->mensagem;
    }

    public function getTags()
    {
        return $this->tags;
    }

}
```

Para utilizar a classe:

```
$mensagem = "Partiu #ferias #praia #feliz #so-pt";

$msg = new Mensagem($mensagem);

var_dump($msg);

//Retorna:

object(Mensagem)#1 (2) {
  ["mensagem":protected]=>
  string(35) "Partiu #ferias #praia #feliz #so-pt"
  ["tags":protected]=>
  array(4) {
    [0]=>
    string(6) "ferias"
    [1]=>
    string(5) "praia"
    [2]=>
    string(5) "feliz"
    [3]=>
    string(5) "so"
  }
}
```

Para a busca utilize o seguinte `SELECT`:

```
SELECT mensagem FROM mensagens
JOIN mensagens_tags ON mensagens_id_mensagem = id_mensagem
JOIN tags ON tags_id_tag = id_tag
WHERE nome = 'tag';
```

Exemplo do banco no [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/bb65d6/1).

Os próximos passos são construir a rotina que irá persistir as tags no banco (inserir as novas tags e manter as antigas) e o sistema para a busca. Isso eu deixo com você.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta mais do que completa, mas me surgiram algumas dúvidas: você disse que faria uma tabela só para as tags, mas, eu não vejo por quê, seria uma tabela somente para cadastro das palavras? Em relação à classe `Mensagem`, como ele pode retornar aquilo sendo que vc não faz nenhum `return` no `__construct`, apenas nas funções `getMensagem` e `getTags` que nem são utilizadas? Obrigado e desculpe pela minha ignorância se for o caso.

Comment: É por causa do var_dump, ele é uma função especial para o dump de objetos. Para utilizar com echo você usa o getMensagem e getTags

Comment: Entendi, obrigado!

Comment: Sobre a tabela separada, a ideia é a normalização mesmo. Assim não temos por exemplo duplicação de tags. A longo prazo ira facilitar a busca também

Comment: E se, futuramente eu quisesse fazer uma contagem pra saber as tags mais utilizadas (semelhante ao tranding tops do Twitter), qual seria o melhor caminho a seguir? Obrigado novamente.

Comment: A partir da query postada, basta um count() e group by de nome da tag, sem a parte do where.

Comment: Entendi, muito obrigado! Caso encontre problemas retorno aqui para pedir ajuda, ainda estou meio confuso com algumas coisas, principalmente a utilização do `JOIN` já que é a primeira vez que utilizo o mesmo, mas acredito que na prática eu consiga entender melhor.

Comment: Igor, a ideia é que você crie outras perguntas. O modelo do stack overflow é diferente de um forum. Mais informações em [tour]

Comment: Farei isso. Obrigado.

Comment: Existem outras perguntas aqui que podem te ajudar. Basta pesquisar um pouco, caso não encontre a resposta faca uma nova pergunta.