# Como encontrar hashtags numa string e armazená-las num array?

Tags: php, string, regex

Eu tenho um sistema de postagem de conteúdo em uma determinada rede social da nossa empresa.

Quando o usuário digitar o texto com `hashtags`, preciso detectar todas elas e armazená-las num array.

Exemplo:

> Olá, estou postando essa #pergunta no #stackoverlow. 
>   Espero que encontre boas #respostas.

Quero que me retorne:

```
array('pergunta', 'stackoverlow', 'respostas');
```

Lembrando que, se a hashtag conter caracteres com acentuação, os mesmos também devem ser processados.

Exemplo:

```
#notícias
#sãoPaulo
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3060756/4056678

Comment: Se existir a possibilidade da hashtag iniciar ou possuir caracteres com acentos a solução irá falhar. Para evitar isso pode-se usar a REGEX `#([^\s]*)

Comment: Se usar o modificador u como @rray mostrou, não tem problema

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Acredito que essa regex resolva o problema, é feito a combinação incialmente de `#` seguido por qualquer caracter no intervalo de (a-z, 0-9), os parâmetros `i` significa que a combinação será case insensitive, já o `u` adicione suporte a caracteres com multibyte.

```
<?php

   $str = '#pergunta no #stackoverlow #notícias 2015 #sãoPaulo';
   preg_match_all('/#\w+/iu', $str, $itens);

   echo "<pre>";
   print_r($itens);
```

Saída:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => #pergunta
            [1] => #stackoverlow
            [2] => #notícias
            [3] => #sãoPaulo
        )

)
```

O @Wallace Maxters, pediu para remover o `#` da caputra, @Guilherme Lautert sugeriu alterar a regex para: `(?<=#)\w+/iu`, utilizando o Lookbehind positivo, que verifica se o caracter existe porém não o captura.

**Leitura recomendada**

[Significado de ?: ?= ?! ?= ?! em uma regex](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/13598/91)

Comment: Interessante é que você não usou o parentesis. Realmente ajuda a diminuir o número de itens retornado, isso é bom. +1

Comment: Eu tinha colocado parenteses ... dai vi que tinha coisas a mais rs.

Comment: Quero um jeito para não repetir a hashtag e ao mesmo tempo não repetir, desconsiderando o CASE da string. Só que isso é outra pergunta

Comment: Deixa te perguntar @rray: Na pergunta, não sei se notou, está retornado um array das hastags, porém sem a `#` antes. Para remover isso, já na expressão regular, é muito difícil?

Comment: @WallaceMaxters. Estou tentando, minha ideia é fazer um grupo vazio para `#`, acho que resolve, ainda não consegui.

Comment: A não ser que você processo o sustenido e depois o grupo e pega o `$matches[1]`, estou certo?

Comment: `/(?<=#)\w+/iu` https://regex101.com/r/zO9kC9/1

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert eu não tenho acesso, hehe mas valeu mesmo assim eu não lembrava qual era o simbolo do grupo vazio.

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert, que massa :D, testei aqui, funcinou.

Comment: Add na sua resposta como complementar, no caso de não querer capturar o `#` junto = D

Comment: @GuilhermeLautert, vou adicionar, obrigado por essa solução.

Comment: Eu também não lembrei do modificador `u`, estamos quites hehe.

Comment: Que massa @GuilhermeLautert. Isso é muito bom, não sabia que esse cara servia pra isso!

Comment: Massa, @rray. Adicionaria apenas a flag m `/#\w+/ium` caso receba textos cumpridos.

Answer (score 8):

Utilizando o comentário do @renan.

A alterando a resposta la dada:

```
$tweet = "this has a #hashtag a  #badhash-tag and a #goodhash_tag";

preg_match_all("/(#[^ #]+)/", $tweet, $matches);

var_dump( $matches );
```

Assim ele busca por qualquer coisa exceto ""(espaço), e o proprio `#`, que tenha `#` a frente.

[regex101](https://regex101.com/r/aQ2yV7/2)

Answer (score 3):

Outra forma é casar na regex a tag com hashtag e separar somente o grupo com :

```
function extractTags($mensagem)
{
    // Casa tags como #dia #feliz #chateado
    // Não casa caracteres especias #so-pt
    $pattern = '/#(\w+)/u';

    // Alternativa para incluir outros caracteres
    // Basta incluir entre os colchetes
    //$pattern = '/#([\w-]+)/u';

    preg_match_all($pattern, $mensagem, $tags);

    // Utiliza o vetor com os grupos capturados entre parenteses
    return $tags[1];
}
```

Extrai essa função de uma resposta que dei anteriormente em outra pergunta: [Sistema de hashtags em PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/66322/sistema-de-hashtags-em-php/66365#66365)

Answer (score 0):

Em PHP você utiliza a função preg_replace, com o regex abaixo, ele vai buscar todas as palavras que contenham # e retornar em matches

```
preg_replace('/\#[A-Za-z-0-9]+/m',$string,$matches);
var_dump( $matches );
```

Comment: Gilmar, seria interessante adicionar alguma explicação de como funciona o código proposto.