# Como tirar a cerquilha # dos textos com o beautifulsoup

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou com problemas para retirar as cerquilhas, mais conhecidas como hashtags de um texto.

**Exemplo de texto:**

```
#mãe #euteamo #presente
```

**como eu gostaria:**

```
mãe euteamo presente
```

Estou utilizando o seguinte comando:

```
def remove_tags(texto):
  
  soup = BeautifulSoup(texto)
  texto_sem_tags = soup.get_text()
  return texto_sem_tags
```

Comment: `return texto.replace("#", "")`

Comment: Obrigado, deu super certo <3

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: O problema desse `replace` é que se tiver qualquer `#` (mesmo se não for parte de uma hashtag), também será removido. Pra pegar somente hashtags, teria que fazer algo [assim](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/93279/112052)

Answer (score -2):

Oii!

Creio que assim irá funcionar:

```
def remove_tags(texto):
  
  soup = BeautifulSoup(texto)
  texto_sem_tags = soup.get_text()
  texto_sem_tags = texto_sem_tags.replace('#', '')
  return texto_sem_tags
```

Apliquei um replace após você pegar o texto entre as tags.